# Loop over variable session array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, session-variables

Building a cart that stores the selected cart items in a session array until checkout. The array is stored as:  $_SESSION ['cart'] ['items'] ['item number'] ... -> sub array fields like quantity, SKU etc. etc.

The output is as shown below, I am trying to figure out how to loop over all the sub arrays QUANTITY fields to get a total items in cart count. But since the 'item number' part of the array keys will change for each new/different product added to the cart, I cant figure out how to use a wildcard to represent that part of the KEY name in the foreach loop. Just to see any output I have tried:

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items']['*']['quantity'] AS $key => $value) {echo $value;}
```

The array is stored/out put like this:

```
[cart] => Array
        (
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [RIF12345] => Array
                        (
                            [SKU] => RIF12345
                            [Brand] => Freemal
                            [Model] => AR3456BA
                            [Price] => 1230.55
                            [SalePrice] => 0.00
                            [Stock] => 12
                            [quantity] => 2
                        )

                    [11111111] => Array
                        (
                            [SKU] => 11111111
                            [Brand] => Marks
                            [Model] => 546454
                            [Price] => 6000.00
                            [SalePrice] => 4500.50
                            [Stock] => 15
                            [quantity] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

Am I approaching this loop from the wrong method? How do I write this foreach loop to accomplish what i am trying to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about this:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $ItemNumber => $Item)
 {$quantity+= $Item['quantity'];}
echo $quantity;
```

Comment: Gives me error notices:  Notice: Undefined variable: quantity in --   but it does output a proper total of 3 --- how can it output a correct total from $quantity but tell me it's undefined? is it because i dont declare it as NULL or something before the loop?

Comment: probably. try doing `$quantity = 0` before